# Colorectal examinations

Tags: terminology, gastroenterology, colon, anus, colonoscopy

This question was sparked by [this discussion](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/19019) about the sigmoid and rectum.

When looking at the colorectal medical examination techniques, for want of a better term, there are the sopical examinations (those named with the suffix *[-scopy](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/-scopy)* - involving the use of in instrument for viewing).

From what I understand, you have **colonoscopy** (examination  of the entire colon with an endoscope) and **sigmoidoscopy** (examination of the sigmoid colon with an endoscope).

Is there such an examination as **anusoscopy** or **rectumoscopy**?  What about **colorectoscopy**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various terms exist.

**[Proctoscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proctoscopy)** is a collective term for the examination of the anus, rectum and sigmoid colon (one or all of them).

[**Anoscopy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anoscopy) is the investigation of the anus (only) using an anoscope.

**Rectoscopy** is the investigation of the rectum (only) using a rectoscope.

**[Sigmoidoscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoidoscopy)** is an examination of the rectum and sigmoid colon using  a sigmoidoscope.

**[Colonoscopy](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/diagnostic-tests/colonoscopy),** also called **lower endoscopy,** is an examination of the rectum and colon, including the sigmoid colon, using a colonoscope.

Combined terms, such as [**rectosigmoidoscopy**](https://www.healio.com/gastroenterology/inflammatory-bowel-disease/news/online/%7B087f3b96-f1c7-41b3-a4cd-65cf2483dc19%7D/rectosigmoidoscopy-colonoscopy-show-strong-agreement-in-disease-activity-assessment-in-uc), are less commonly used.

On the other hand, when it comes to upper endoscopy, more known as gastroscopy, the combined term **[esophagogastroduodenoscopy](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1851864-overview)** is commonly used in the medical documentation or literature.

Here are [Current Procedural Terminology (CPT) codes for the investigations of lower gastrointestinal tract](https://www.asge.org/docs/default-source/new-content/practice-support/asge_primer_2017_pgs117-125-single-page.pdf) with exact definitions and descriptions. The terms used include anoscopy, proctosigmoidoscopy, flexible sigmoidoscopy and colonoscopy.

Comment: What about [*Proctosigmoidoscopy*](http://icd9cm.chrisendres.com/index.php?action=procrec&recordid=1762)? :-) It's weird that Rectoscopy, when Googled comes up with [this ScienceDirect page](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/rectoscopy) headed *rectoscopy* but talks about *proctoscopy*.

Comment: I added a link to CPT codes in my answer.

Comment: Great post and answer between professionals in our new scope! :)